# Simple jquery function does no work on click event

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and trying to learn it by example. I see there is a id selector for handling events. Here is a very simple function to handle a click event of a button. Unfortunately it does not work as expected. I could not find any syntax errors. I'm using jquery-3.2.1 for this.

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is a test</title>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="test">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js file:**

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    alert('You clicked me');
});
```

Comment: You need to have the jQuery file above your custom file. There should be an error in your console saying `$ is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think you need to bind the event to the button after your page is completely rendered...

To do that use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").click(function () {
   alert('You clicked me');
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change 2 things:

- Load your main JavaScript file after JQuery instead of before
- Postpone binding to the click event until after the document has loaded, using

`$(document).ready( ...)`

See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/